# Unable to pass Saved values in formParam of same request

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I have saved `'current_account_id'` and `'current_workspace_id'`

in below code. Want to use those IDs in next request as I have to make it dynamic so I replaced "505520" with `"${accountID}"` and "505519" with `"${workspaceID}"` **but it doesnt work and throws "No attribute named 'accountID' is defined"**

**However it works on 'Logout' request.** Can anyone tell how to solve this?

```
.exec(http("Login")
   .post("/j_security_check")
   .headers(headers_9)
   .formParam("j_username", username + ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt(endNum))
   .formParam("j_password", password)
   .resources(
    http("Fetch_IDs")
   .get("/desktop/side_nav.jsp")
   .check(regex("""current_account_id=(\d+)""").saveAs("accountID"))
   .check(regex("""current_workspace_id=(\d+)""").saveAs("workspaceID"))
   .headers(headers_5),
    http("request_11")
   .get("/desktop/dashboard/index.jsp")
   .headers(headers_5),
    http("request_12")
   .get("/global_nav.jsp")
   .headers(headers_5),
    http("request_13")
   .post("/eventDataController")
   .headers(headers_9)
   .formParam("action", "viewevents")
   .formParam("objectId", "")
   .formParam("type", "Desktop")
   .formParam("dashboardType", "desktop_events")
   .formParam("forceReplace", "true")
        // Doesnt work 
   .formParam("current_account_id", "${accountID}")
   .formParam("current_workspace_id", "${workspaceID}")
   .formParam("skipAccountCheck", "")
   .formParam("skipWorkspaceCheck", ""),
    http("request_14")
   .post("/savedsearchdatacontroller")
   .headers(headers_9)
   .formParam("action", "dashboard_view")
   .formParam("dashboardType", "Desktop")
   .formParam("current_account_id", "505520")
   .formParam("current_workspace_id", "505519"),
    http("request_15")
   .post("/wizardDataController")
   .headers(headers_9)
   .formParam("action", "view")
   .formParam("current_account_id", "505520")
   .formParam("current_workspace_id", "505519")))

 .exec(http("Logout")
   .post("/logoutcontroller")
   .headers(headers_9)
   .formParam("action", "logout")
   .formParam("undefined", "")
                //Here it works and fetches value
   .formParam("current_account_id", "${accountID}")
   .formParam("current_workspace_id", "${workspaceID}")
  )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can't use 'accountID' from the session because it's not set yet.

Requests that you fetch from resources block are executed in parallel. That means you can't reuse a variable saved from a request into an other request if both are in the same resources block.

Moreover, the username have always the same random number for each user.

```
.formParam("j_username", username + ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt(endNum))
```

If you want a different random number for each user you need to pass a function to formParam like this:

```
.formParam("j_username", _ => username + ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt(endNum))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a session to get that like this:

1. Declare a global variable:

   ```
   var accountIDString = "";
   var workspaceIDString = "";
   ```
2. Create another exec the following way:

   ```
   .exec(session =>{
    accountIDString = session.get("accountID").asOption[String].toString();

   workIDString = session.get("workID").asOption[String].toString();    
   })

   .exec(http("Logout")
      .post("/logoutcontroller")
      .headers(headers_9)
      .formParam("action", "logout")
      .formParam("undefined", "")
               //Here it works and fetches value
      .formParam("current_account_id", "${accountIDString}")
      .formParam("current_workspace_id", "${workspaceIDString}"))
   ```

And it would work.

Comment: Nope, What I have mentioned is it works for .exec(http("Logout") request. It does not work with .exec(http("Login"). Ids which I have saved are okay but In same .exec() it wont fetch.

Comment: @Peter Ok. But with the method I showed it would always work.